# Aligning a div inside A H2 tag

Tags: html, css

I have an issue where i need to insert a div inside a H2 Tag.

Is that possible. I think it should.
Only think is i dont know how to get it done. I have tried the following

**HTML**

```
<h2 id="strap">Blah Blah & Some More Blah Blah Blah    
    <div class="section contain">            
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/BlahBlah" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><img alt="facebook" src="<%=SkinPath %>img/social/fb.png"/></a>
        <a href="http://twitter.com/BlahBlah" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><img alt="twitter" src="<%=SkinPath %>img/social/tw.png"/></a>
        <a href="http://BlahBlah.wordpress.com/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><img alt="blog" src="<%=SkinPath %>img/social/wp.png"/></a>          
    </div>
</h2>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nNuwT/3/)

I want the div element(Social Icons) to come on the same line. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: If I was being rude, there would be name-calling.

Comment: Buddy, it you cant help, take a hike. I definitely do not need you unwanted suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use an `h2` inside an `h2`. If you change the inner `h2` to `span` it will be inline.

Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/nNuwT/2/

Comment: Actually i dont need the second H2. Check my Edit... I just want the Social Icons inline with the H2 text

Comment: Still, skip405 is right, change the div to a span and you'll get what you are after. Also, you'll have more valid HTML: putting a div inside an H2 is strictly not valid HTML, I believe.

Comment: @HansRoerdinkholder Is there a tool to validate HTML structure?

Answer (score 1):

Demo [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sethuramanP/nNuwT/6/)

**CSS**

```
.contain
{
    display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need I think,

[Forked Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nBtRE/)

Hope this works for you....

```
#strap{
float:left;
line-height: 100%;
display:block;
width: 100%;
background: #dddddd;
 padding: 10px;
}
.section {
float:right;
display: inline-block;
}
.section span {
font-size: 18px;
margin-right: 5px;
display:block;
float: left;
}
.section img {
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
}
```